# TypeError: 'NodeView' object does not support item assignment - NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx

I'm working through this tutorial: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/networkx-python-graph-tutorial

```
import itertools
import copy
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
nodelist = pd.read_csv('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brooksandrew/f989e10af17fb4c85b11409fea47895b/raw/a3a8da0fa5b094f1ca9d82e1642b384889ae16e8/nodelist_sleeping_giant.csv')

g = nx.Graph()

for i, nlrow in nodelist.iterrows():
    g.node[nlrow['id']] = nlrow[1:].to_dict()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-35b1a259a02d> in <module>()
      1 for i, nlrow in nodelist.iterrows():
----> 2     g.node[nlrow['id']] = nlrow[1:].to_dict()

TypeError: 'NodeView' object does not support item assignment
```

The result from running this should look like:

```
[('rs_end_south', {'X': 1865, 'Y': 1598}),
 ('w_gy2', {'X': 2000, 'Y': 954}),
 ('rd_end_south_dupe', {'X': 273, 'Y': 1869}),
 ('w_gy1', {'X': 1184, 'Y': 1445}),
 ('g_rt', {'X': 908, 'Y': 1378}),
 ('v_rd', {'X': 258, 'Y': 1684}),
 ('g_rs', {'X': 1676, 'Y': 775}),
 ('rc_end_north', {'X': 867, 'Y': 618}),
 ('v_end_east', {'X': 2131, 'Y': 921}),
 ('rh_end_south', {'X': 721, 'Y': 1925})]
```

But I can't get python to output the `id` followed by the dict.

Comment: @Murmel yes thank you. Any idea on the error though?

Comment: Which python version are you using? Could be an Python2 vs Python3 issue

Comment: @Murmel python3

Comment: I don't think so because the tutorial was written September of 2017, and he's using `print()`

Comment: You could use `g.node[nlrow['id']].update(nlrow[1:].to_dict())` instead of `g.node[nlrow['id']] = nlrow[1:].to_dict()`

Comment: @Murmel That worked! Thank you

Comment: Note - you're using networkx version 2.0, right?  It's very recent, and so I suspect that this is an incompatibility from the person writing it using version 1.11.   I think networkx provides ways to do what these commands are trying to do without directly editing the underlying data structure of the graph.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Instead of:

```
g.node[nlrow['id']] = nlrow[1:].to_dict()
```

use:

```
g.nodes[nlrow['id']].update(nlrow[1:].to_dict())
```

This works because `g.nodes[x]` is nothing else than a dict. Nevertheless, I'm not sure why the documentation proposes the other way.

**Note:**

Joel made a good point [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045155/typeerror-nodeview-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-networkx#comment81041787_47045155), which I think is very important:

> Note - you're using networkx version 2.0, right? It's very recent, and
>   so I suspect that this is an incompatibility from the person writing
>   it using version 1.11. I think networkx provides ways to do what these
>   commands are trying to do without directly editing the underlying data
>   structure of the graph.

So my solution basically works by having knowledge about the underlying data structure and not using the *public api*, which is not good programming style.

[Since Version 2.4](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.4.html#deprecations), `G.node` is deprecated in favor of `G.nodes` (Thank you, WiccanKarnak).

Comment: You might want to consider changing g.node to g.nodes as indicated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58598016/6946802