# AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'node'

Tags: python, graph, cluster-computing, networkx, knn

I have bellow python code to build knn graph but I have an error: AttributeError: 'Graph' object has no attribute 'node'. It seems that the nx.Graph() has no node attribute but I don't know what should I replace with that.

```
import networkx as nx
def knn_graph(df, k, verbose=False):
    points = [p[1:] for p in df.itertuples()]
    g = nx.Graph()
    if verbose: print ("Building kNN graph (k = %d)" % (k))
    iterpoints = tqdm(enumerate(points), total=len(points)) if verbose else enumerate(points)
    for i, p in iterpoints:
        distances = map(lambda x: euclidean_distance(p, x), points)
        closests = np.argsort(distances)[1:k+1] # second trough kth closest
        for c in closests:
            g.add_edge(i, c, weight=distances[c])
        g.node[i]['pos'] = p
    return g
```

Comment: I think it should be `nodes`.

Comment: @Guy I'm sorry but it doesn't work. beacuse i have an error on it: line 178, in __getitem__return self._nodes[n]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @nino can you please post the full traceback

Answer (score 55):

If you are using NetworkX 2.4, use `G.nodes[]` instead of `G.node[]`. The latter attribute is deprecated. See the [release notes](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.4.html#deprecations).

Comment: In my case, I installed NetworkX 2.0 to solve the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I'm using Anaconda3. pip uninstall networkx did not work in Anaconda command window. I opened Anaconda powershell and did pip uninstall networkx and then came back to Anaconda command window to pip install networkx==2.3

After this the error is resolved

Answer (score 0):

For me, this error was related to anaconda and miniconda. I have removed miniconda from WSL and no more errors:

```
remove miniconda
pip install networkx==2.3
```

then run the related code.

Comment: That solution seems specific to you. OP has not specified if working with Anaconda. Besides, if I read you correctly, you are suggesting to mix your conda-installed Python with pip, which is a dangerous path regarding the stability of your environment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35661660)